# Is it Possible Toad for Oracle Automatic Session Recconnect?

Tags: oracle, keyboard-shortcuts, session-timeout, toad, reconnect

I work on Toad for oracle 12.8.0.49.
I lost my session very often. And I get ORA-02329. Because DBA decreased dramatically session connection timeout. So I have to intensively press keyboard shortcut to reconnect all sessions.
Is there any option that toad trigger keyboard shortcut every minute while I am coding. I mean it shouldn't lock the whole toad. It can lock one tab. This is not problem.
By the way I've already assigned a keyboard shortcut to reconnect.

Comment: From my point of view, you should talk to DBA. A *minute*? Why did they do that?

Comment: Open a tab with dbms_output polling, maybe that keeps your connection open.

Comment: What is your keyboard shortcut to reconnect? Alt + S + S + Enter? Or other shortcut that do not need both hand?

Comment: The shortcut is not assigned as default. I did it.  Go to "View" -> "Toad Options" -> "Toolbars/Menus" -> "Shortcuts" -> "Session" -> "Test All Connections (Reconnect).